# WPF Dependency injection

Tags: wpf, xaml, unity-container

Hello i have a problem with dependency injection in WPF application. Here is my code:
App.xaml.cs:

```
  IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterType<ICarViewModel, CarViewModel>();
  container.RegisterType<MainWindow>();
  MainWindow mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
  mainWindow.Show();
```

CarViewModel.cs:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars{ get; } = new ObservableCollection<Car>()
    {
        new Car() {Name = "Audi"},
        new Car() {Name = "Peugeot"},
        new Car() {Name = "Renault"},
    };
```

CarView.cs:

```
public partial class CarView : UserControl, ICarView
{
    public CarView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CarView(CarViewModel carViewModel) : this()
    {
        DataContext = carViewModel;
    }
}
```

CarView.xaml:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = Cars}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = Name, Mode = OneWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<view:CarView x:Name = "CarViewControl"></view:CarView>
```

Unity container still call only constructor without parameters from CarView.
Thanks for advice

Comment: Take out the parameter-less constructor? It's probably just defaulting to using that one.

Comment: What? Please, show me how to do it?

Comment: You just delete the constructor that doesn't take any parameters, and keep the one that does. Make sure to move the call to `InitializeComponent()` to the constructor that takes parameters and remove the `:this()` call and you should be fine.

Comment: It does not work, must be default constructor?

Comment: can you expand on "it does not work"? Doesn't work how? Compilation error? Runtime error? No error?

Comment: Zde je chyba: <názor: CarView x: Name = "CarViewControl"> </ view: CarView>

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The type 'CarView' cannot have a Name attribute. Value types and types without a default constructor can be used as items within a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Why are you referencing this in a resource dictionary? Your example doesn't mention anything about that.

Comment: I dont know. If i remove x:Name and build, throw NullReferenceException in  InitializeComponent(); in MainWindow constructor.

Comment: What is your CarViewModel code behind?

Comment: `public class CarViewModel : ICarViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars{ get; private set; }
        
        public CarViewModel()
        {

            Car= new ObservableCollection<Car>()
            {
                new Car() {Name = "C1"},new Car() {Name = "C2"},new Car() {Name = "C3"},
            };
        }
    }`

Comment: If i add this line CarView mw = container.Resolve<CarView>(); to App.xaml.cs and i will put breakpoint in CarView constructor in parametr, this constructor will call. but calls separately, not in Window.
           ` IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<MainWindow>();
            container.RegisterType<ICarViewModel, CarViewModel>();
            MainWindow mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
            MachineView mw = container.Resolve<CarView>();
            mainWindow.Show();`

Comment: Where do you register CarView to Unity container?

Comment: I add CarView register, but it not works:
`            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<MainWindow>();
            container.RegisterType<ICarView, CarView>();
            container.RegisterType<ICarViewModel, CarViewModel>();
            MainWindow mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
            mainWindow.Show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the type this way:

```
 container.RegisterType(typeof(MainWindow), typeof(MainWindow), new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter(typeof(CarViewModel), CarViewModelInstance)));
```

Or you can use [InjectionConstructor] attribute on MainWindow constructor:

```
 [InjectionConstructor]
 public CarView(CarViewModel carViewModel) : this()
```

Also, you can pass the [Dependency] attribute on constructor parameter, so Unity will try to resolve value for that parameter from its registered instances:

```
 [InjectionConstructor]
 public CarView([Dependency] CarViewModel carViewModel) : this()
```

The best approach for your example could maybe looks somehow like this:

```
 container.RegisterType<ICarViewModel, CarViewModel>("Car");
 ....
 [InjectionConstructor]
 public CarView([Dependency("Car")] CarViewModel carViewModel) : this()
```

There is a lot of ways to do what you need to do.. More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx

Some test code:

```
 var container1 = new UnityContainer(); 
 container1.RegisterType(typeof(IBar), typeof(Bar), "Bar");
 container1.RegisterType<Foo>();

 public interface IBar
 {
 }

 public class Bar : IBar
 {
 }

 public class Foo
 {
      public IBar Bar
      {
      get;
      private set;
      }

      public Foo()
      {
      }

      [InjectionConstructor]
      public Foo([Dependency("Bar")] Bar bar)
      {
      Bar = bar;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I use last example but still call first (parameter-less) constructor.

Comment: It's strange. The [InjectionConstructor] attribute tells Unity, that this is the one constructor, which have to be called.. I'll take a look.

Comment: Are you sure, that the second constructor is not called at all? I did some tests and code is right. Notice: your first (parameter-less) constructor will be called too (because of ": this()" at the second constructor).

Comment: I tried add two constructors with parameter to MainWindow and add InjectionConstructor attribute and it works corectly. But in CarView dont worked

Comment: Hmm, really strange.. I produced some test code and it works well. I think, that problem is somewhere else (not in the dependency injection construct)..

Comment: Can you show  me your test? Or can you uploaded somewhere whole project?

Comment: I inserted some test code to answer. Dependency injection construct is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120120/discussion-between-bluray-and-paya).